# Buttons aligning to the left of the page at less then 1199px when they should be centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the created the following layout using Bootstrap 5 (link to fiddle below). The rows of buttons are aligned as I wish at 1200px and above but when the XL breakpoint is reached at 1199px, the buttons align to the left of the container instead of being centered.

The fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/xrdcq9g6/11/

This is despite using flexbox to center the content of each row:

```
 <div class="row pb-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-xl-4">
          <p class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"><a href="resources-art-therapy-clinic.html" class="lit-link">Art Therapy<br>Clinical Literature<br>Source Material</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
           <p class="btn btn-warning btn-lg "><a href="#" class="lit-link">Resilience<br>Spiritual Development</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4">
            <p class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"><a href="resources-literature-integrative-medicine.html" class="lit-link">Integrative Medicine</a></p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I can't work out why the buttons are aligning left, so any help much appreciated. The layout is overlaid on a parallax background, so I'm not sure if that's what is preventing content of the rows being centered.

Comment: Your culprits are `row` and/or `col-xl-4` classes. There's a breakpoint defined at 1200px where `col-xl-4` behaves differently. You like one way and not the other way. You could keep wrestling with this, however, do you even need to use row-and-col's for this situation? And, as well in narrow mobile viewports, your buttons would obviously be displayed vertically. So with this in mind, I suggest simplicity by not fussing with rows & cols, and have a parent container with `display: flex`, `flex-wrap: wrap` and some width limiter like `max-width: 900px` on it, then style your children as you may.

Comment: `col-xl-4` applies for >= 1200px. Below that, your columns simple get their width from `.row>*`, which applies `flex-shrink: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 100%;`. So your columns _are_ centered, but because each of them goes over the _full width_, you don't see much of it. And the buttons inside of them are still aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p elements are aligning left because the parent div is full width and the element aligns to the left by default. Apply margin auto to both left and right to this element to center it. In bootstrap this is by adding the class `mx-auto` to the element `<p class="btn btn-arning btn-lg>` as follows:

```
<p class="btn btn-warning btn-lg mx-auto"><a>...</a></p>
```

Marked up fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mj8vanqo/)

Answer (score 1):

For aligning flex children center, you have to apply center properties on the parent div not on the child itself:

```
<div class="col-xl-4" style="display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content: center;">
  <p class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">
      <a href="resources-literature-rudolph-steiner.html" class="lit-link">Rudolph Steiner</a>
  </p>
</div>
```